# Oracle DBMS_ALERT in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, notifications, oracle12c

I have a table (`my_tab`) that contains a STATUS column against a specific ID in this same table.

I need a means of being alerted via a DBMS_ALERT process of when the STATUS column changes value.

I was looking at using a trigger to kick off the ALERT, i.e.:

```
create or replace trigger my_tab_upd after update of status on my_tab for each row
begin
   dbms_alert.signal('mystatusalert', 'changed from '||:old.status||' to '||:new.status||'.');
end;
/
```

With this, how do I now get alerted/notified that this STATUS change has occurred within a PL/SQL procedure to now go off and perform another operation based on this STATUS change?

Further to the above, with my application setup, there will be multiple users. Based on this, how can I target the alert for specific users/sessions so that the correct user gets their alert only and not someone else's.

I am looking at checking the alert from a web based application (Oracle APEX), so don't want to lock the front-end up so any recommendations on this would be good.

An example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I'd send an e-mail to myself. For example:

```
create or replace trigger my_tab_upd 
  after update of status on my_tab 
  for each row
begin
  utl_mail.send (sender     => 'me@company.com',
                 recipients => 'me@company.com',
                 subject    => 'MY_TAB status changed',
                 message    => 'old = ' || :old.status ||', new = ' || :new.status
                );
end;
```

---

`DBMS_ALERT` example: in Scott's schema, I want to notify my stored procedure that something has changed in the `EMP` table and then *do something* (I'll just display the message).

First, create a triggger; alert name is `alert_emp` and will be used later in the stored procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_au_emp
  2    after update on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    dbms_alert.signal
  6      ('alert_emp', 'Salary changed for ' || :new.ename ||
  7                    ' from ' || :old.sal ||
  8                    ' to '   || :new.sal);
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

The procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2    l_msg    varchar2(200);
  3    l_status number;
  4  begin
  5    dbms_alert.register ('alert_emp');
  6    dbms_alert.waitone  ('alert_emp', l_msg, l_status);
  7    dbms_output.put_line(l_msg ||': '|| l_status);
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.
```

Now, execute the procedure:

```
SQL> exec p_test;
```

Here, it is just waiting for something to happen in the EMP table. **In another session** I'm updating the table. Commit is *obligatory*; otherwise, nothing happens. `p_test` will still be waiting.

```
update emp set sal = 1000 where empno = 7369;
commit;
```

In the first session, once `commit` is being executed, screen shows this:
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
Salary changed for SMITH from 800 to 1000: 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Appreciate the response but I actually don't want an email sent. I actually want to be alerted within PL/SQL that the STATUS value has changed, in order for me to be notified.

Comment: OK then, I posted an example of how dbms_alert works. Have a look.

Comment: Great - will take a look.

Comment: Just a couple of questions please: 1) is there a means of checking if an ALERT has already been registered so that it doesn't get registered again? 2) With my application  setup, there will be multiple users. Based on this, how can I target alert for specific users/sessions so that the correct user gets their alert and not someone elses?

Comment: Another question, in addition to the above: 3) Is there any means of your p_test procedure not locking a session until the COMMIT is issued but somehow running in the background, possibly a DBMS_SCHEDULED job - hope this makes sense?

Comment: **1.** Re-register it again, no problem. Or first run DBMS_ALERT.REMOVE, then REGISTER.  **2.** It is not *user* that is registered for an alert, but *stored procedure*. Though, you can include something like `if user = 'SCOTT' then register_it else don't end if;` Once again: user won't be alerted (you'd use my first suggestion - mail - for that). **3.** Sure, you can schedule it, why not.

Comment: With the scheduled job, which I am a bit unsure, since multiple users will be using the app and waiting for the DBMS_ALERT: Q1) will this scheduled job be kicked off only once for all users? Q2) using your example above, could you please add to your answer the steps to create this scheduled job, as I assume that it will need to continually check for a change from the alert Q3) is my assumption in Q2 correct or can this scheduled job check every 2 mins even though an update can occur beforehand? Just trying to understand how to setup this scheduled job so that it's checking for an update.

Comment: Sorry @Littlefoot - are you able to please assist with the queries in my previous comment, if possible as you've been a great help.

Comment: The registration is valid for the session that performs it and is closed after the session is terminated. So *you can schedule it* (as @Littlefoot suggests) but you will lost all *signals* fired between the runs of the periodic job. Although the Oracle documentation is not explicite here, the test shows that *unsubscibed signals* are discarded. You may switch to `AQ` to get the message *persistance* but it seems an *overkill* here. You should *push* the event to the subscribers and not let them  *poll* the database - a sort of the original e-mail proposal.

Comment: Well, yes - @MarmiteBomber said it all, there's nothing I'd like to add to it.