# Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER job to monitor a DBMS_ALERT

Tags: oracle, plsql, notifications, oracle12c

Env: Oracle 12c R2

Trying to understand what the best approach would be to set up an Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER job that would be used to monitor a DBMS_ALERT trigger that checks when a specific column value changes within a table.

The thing is, this table column value change will sometimes occur on a frequent basis and sometimes it may only occur twice a day but I will need to monitor this column change via the DBMS_ALERT.

The trigger I have is as follows and I have a procedure called `check_signal` that checks for the signal that I wish to use within the DBMS_SCHEDULER job.

The goal that I am trying to achieve is that I am going to have the situation where I will need to run say, three jobs:

```
Job1
Job2
Job3
```

The thing is, the payload returned from `Job1` is required and and passed as parameters into `Job2` and again, the payload returned from Job2 is required and passed as parameters into `Job3`.

It is this wait/alert that I am trying to achieve through the use of DBMS_ALERTS.

```
create or replace trigger my_tab_upd after update of status on my_tab for each row
begin
   dbms_alert.signal('mystatusalert', 'changed from '||:old.status||' to '||:new.status||'.');
end;
/
```

This will be used via a web-based application which is used by multiple users.

Just unsure on how to setup this scheduled job that will continuously check for the alert and then be used within the web app.

If there is a better means than DBMS_ALERT, then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is simple, while *polling for events every N seconds* you get an *average delay N/2 seconds and maximal delay of N seconds*.

In context of `DBMS_ALERT` you should re-think this approach, as this will implement *polling with wait on the event*.

The periodically executed jobs make basically tho thinks:

- `DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER` on an event name
- wait with `DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE`

Assume that the DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs runs every 10 seconds  and it is started in the phase with frequent signalling. So the first execution returns quickly after receiving an event.

The second execution falls in the quite period, so the job will *wait hours to get an event*.

I think this is not what you expect as

1) the waiting job will have an open session - what you want to avoid as follows from [you other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61284122/4808122)

*You may use `timeout = 0` in the `DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE`, but this will return close to no events, except those fired accidentally  between the `REGISTER` and `WAITONE`*

2) if in the first 10 seconds two events are signalled, the second one will be lost as at the signaling time the subscribing job is not active and no registration exists.

Comment: Appreciate the response and it seems like DBMS_ALERT is not the best approach. I have updated my original post to show exact scenario that I am trying to achieve, re: Job1,Job2 and Job3. Would appreciate any other possible solutions/suggestions.

Comment: My final advice @tonyf do not let the web app people ask how can they query the change in the database; ask them how can you post a change in database to them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just for my understanding, could you please expand on this process, i.e. how can you post a change in database to them - as I will certainly look at this approach as right now, I am not entirely sure how to approach this.